# How combine UITableView reorder rows with UIDropDelegate

Tags: uitableview, drag-and-drop, ios11

Using iOS 11 I'd like a UITableview to support both existing row re-ordering using the standard row drag handle *and* also accept dropping images via the new UITableViewDropDelegate protocol. Using the standard examples I can accept images using the tableview.dropDelegate working OK, 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_table_views?language=objc

but as soon as I assign the dropDelegate, the existing row-reordering no longer works. I tried setting the tableview's dragDelegate and returning an array with single UIDragItem (same doc examples), but this still does not give the existing row re-ordering and the complete cell view can be dragged to "anywhere" in the app, not just in the tableview. Also the animations that show the re-order insertion position do not work.

Any idea if this (combining drag/drop + reorder) is at all possible, or should row re-ordering be handled by the dragDelegate/dropDelegate too? Plus: any example on how to do that?

Comment: you can check this cs193p course lecture 12, the professor gave the example of how to do this in collection view, start from the middle https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCJ79tknk1I

Comment: Thanks, I got it working based on that lecture,